# Event Sourcing - Apache Kafka + Kafka Streams - How to assure atomicity / transactionality

Tags: apache-kafka, event-sourcing, apache-kafka-streams

I'm evaluating Event Sourcing with Apache Kafka Streams to see how viable it is for complex scenarios. As with relational databases I have come across some cases were atomicity/transactionality is essential:

Shopping app with two services:

- **OrderService**: has a Kafka Streams store with the orders (OrdersStore)
- **ProductService**: has a Kafka Streams store (ProductStockStore) with the products and their stock.

Flow:

1. OrderService publishes an OrderCreated event (with productId, orderId, userId info)
2. ProductService gets the OrderCreated event and queries its KafkaStreams Store (ProductStockStore) to check if there is stock for the product. If there is stock it publishes an OrderUpdated event (also with productId, orderId, userId info)

The point is that this event would be listened by ProductService Kafka Stream, which would process it to decrease the stock, so far so good.

But, imagine this:

1. Customer 1 places an order, order1 (there is a stock of 1 for the product)
2. Customer 2 places concurrently another order, order2, for the same product (stock is still 1)
3. ProductService processes order1 and sends a message OrderUpdated to decrease the stock. This message is put in the topic after the one from order2 -> OrderCreated
4. ProductService processes order2-OrderCreated and sends a message OrderUpdated to decrease the stock again. This is incorrect since it will introduce an inconsistency (stock should be 0 now).

The obvious problem is that our materialized view (the store) should be updated directly when we process the first OrderUpdated event. However the only way (I know) of updating the Kafka Stream Store is publishing another event (OrderUpdated) to be processed by the Kafka Stream. This way we can't perform this update transactionally.

I would appreciate ideas to deal with scenarios like this.

**UPDATE:** I'll try to clarify the problematic bit of the problem:

**ProductService** has a Kafka Streams Store, **ProductStock** with this stock `(productId=1, quantity=1)`

**OrderService** publishes two **OrderPlaced** events on the **orders topic**:

- `Event1 (key=product1, productId=product1, quantity=1, eventType="OrderPlaced")`
- `Event2 (key=product1, productId=product1, quantity=1, eventType="OrderPlaced")`

**ProductService** has a consumer on the orders topic. For simplicity let's suppose a **single partition** to assure messages consumption in order. This consumer executes the following logic:

```
if("OrderPlaced".equals(event.get("eventType"))){

    Order order = new Order();
    order.setId((String)event.get("orderId"));
    order.setProductId((Integer)(event.get("productId")));
    order.setUid(event.get("uid").toString());

    // QUERY PRODUCTSTOCK TO CHECK AVAILABILITY
    Integer productStock = getProductStock(order.getProductId());

    if(productStock > 0) {
        Map<String, Object> event = new HashMap<>();
        event.put("name", "ProductReserved");
        event.put("orderId", order.getId());
        event.put("productId", order.getProductId());

        // WRITES A PRODUCT RESERVED EVENT TO orders topic
        orderProcessor.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(event).build(), 500);
    }else{
        //XXX CANCEL ORDER
    }
}
```

**ProductService** also has a Kafka Streams processor that is responsible to update the stock:

```
KStream<Integer, JsonNode> stream = kStreamBuilder.stream(integerSerde, jsonSerde, "orders");
stream.xxx().yyy(() -> {...}, "ProductsStock");
```

**Event1** would be processed first and since there is still 1 available product it would generate the **ProductReserved** event.

Now, it's **Event2**'s turn. If it is consumed by **ProductService consumer** BEFORE the **ProductService Kafka Streams Processor** processes the ProductReseved event generated by **Event1**, the consumer would still see that the ProductStore stock for product1 is 1, generating a ProductReserved event for Event2, then producing an inconsistency in the system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is a little late for your original question, but let me answer anyway for completeness.

There are a number of ways to solve this problem, but I would encourage addressing this is an event driven way. This would mean you (a) validate there is enough stock to process the order and (b) reserve the stock as a single, all within a single KStreams operation. The trick is to rekey by productId, that way you know orders for the same product will be executed sequentially on the same thread (so you can't get into the situation where Order1 & Order2 reserve stock of the same product twice).

There is a post that talks discusses how to do this: https://www.confluent.io/blog/building-a-microservices-ecosystem-with-kafka-streams-and-ksql/

Maybe more usefully there is some sample code also showing how it can be done:
https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/1cbcaddd85457b39ee6e9050164dc619b08e9e7d/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/microservices/InventoryService.java#L76

Note how in this KStreams code the first line rekeys to productId, then a Transformer is used to (a) validate there is sufficient stock to process the order **and** (b) reserve the stock required by updating the state store. This is done atomically, using Kafka's Transactions feature.

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for your answer, I’ve finally had time to work on this again. It works fine but there’s something I don’t understand: the KStream is created from the orders topic so why does selecting a new key (product) change the ordering of the elements processed to products? I mean the original source is an order topic partition, how come it is redistributed to products now? Is there any documentation about this behavior?

Answer (score 4):

This same problem is typical in assuring consistency in any distributed system. Instead of going for strong consistency, typically the process manager/saga pattern is used. This is somewhat similar to the 2-phase commit in distributed transactions but implemented explicitly in application code. It goes like this:

The Order Service asks the Product Service to reserve N items. The Product Service either accepts the command and reduces stock or rejects the command if it doesn't have enough items available. Upon positive reply to the command the Order Service can now emit OrderCreated event (although I'd call it OrderPlaced, as "placed" sounds mode idiomatic to the domain and "created" is more generic, but that's a detail). The Product Service either listens for OrderPlaced events or an explicit ConfirmResevation command is sent to it. Alternatively, if something else happened (e.g. failed to clear funds), an appropriate event can be emitted or CancelReservation command sent explicitly to the ProductService. To cater for exceptional circumstances, the ProductService may also have a scheduler (in KafkaStreams punctuation can come in handy for this) to cancel reservations that weren't confirmed or aborted within a timeout period.

The technicalities of the orchestration of the two services and handling the error conditions and compensating actions (cancelling reservation in this case) can be handled in the services directly, or in an explicit Process Manager component to segregate this responsibility. Personally I'd go for an explicit Process Manager that could be implemented using Kafka Streams Processor API.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. If I got it right the Kafka Streams Processor API allows us to write to a remote store, doesn't it? So you're recommending to use another service, ProcessManagerService, that would use the Processor API to interact with the other services' stores, my doubt is: do all messages produced by the services have to be processed by this manager or only those necessary for the saga commit/ rollback? If you have any further reading about this it'd be great.

Comment: A process manager wouldn't directly interact with remote stores, but could just send appropriate messages via Kafka and the respective services would handle them as part of their contract. The Process Manager can be its own service but doesn't have to be. It could be just part of the service that begins the flow, in this case the Order Service. It depends if you prefer the overall solution be more concise or more de-coupled.

Comment: Hi Michal, after some time weighing your answer I keep struggling to solve this problem so I unaccepted the answer. Let me justify it: I think your proposal of using a Saga pattern is completely correct but the implementation is still not clear. You stated: `The Order Service asks the Product Service to reserve N items. The Product Service either accepts the command and reduces stock or rejects the command if it doesn't have enough items available.` This is the problematic part: ProductService has to check the stock to accept/reject the command. Two concurrent commands would check the stock..

Comment: ...In case there is 1 product in the stock, two concurrent reserve product commands could succeed. I'm updating the question to describe the scenario more clearly.

Comment: If you use Kafka Streams to implement the Product Service you will not have this problem. You just need to partition these messages by product id. Message processing within a partition is sequential. All requests to reserve the same product will go to the same task and it will process the message and update its state store sequentially. Starting from Kafka v0.11 you can even enable Exactly-once-Semantics to have this done transactionally to avoid duplicate reservations in case of failures followed by retries. Otherwise you have to make sure your state store updates are idempotent.

Comment: Michal thanks  for taking the time to answer. The last paragraph of the updated question is what really makes me doubt about the atomicity of the product reservation.

Comment: I just want to add a very good presentation which focuses on the usage of sagas for dealing with the problem of transactional integrity acorss distributed microservices. Here you go: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YPbGW3Fnmbc